# Django REST Framework - API Authentication - Authorize Apps instead of Users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Being new to Django, i was wondering if there's a "fast" and "elegant" way to replace the default model against which Django creates access tokens for API authentication ?

I use plugins like "django-rest-framework-simplejwt", and by default they work only with the user model.

The point is to let users create apps, and each app has its own API access and refresh tokens !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up developing my own app authentication system !

1. Authentication backend: Which is supposed to handle apps authentication.
2. Middlewares: To verify the existence of a Bearer token and checks if it's still valid, and also sets app into request, so "app" can be accessible from "request.app" (just like request.user).
3. Decorators: To execute the previous middlewares right before the views.

This is a sample of what a view looks like.

```
@method_decorator([require_POST, AuthorizeTokensAndSetApp], name='dispatch')
class PaymentBillCreateView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [MyTokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [UserIsAllowedToAccess, AppIsAllowedToAccess]
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
```